About $\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{x^a-x^b}{\log(x)}\bigg)^2 \text{d}x=\log\bigg(\frac{(2a+1)^{2a+1}(2b+1)^{2b+1}}{(a+b+1)^{2(a+b+1)}}\bigg)$
For $a>-\frac{1}{2}, b>-\frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{x^a-x^b}{\log(x)}\bigg)^2 \text{d}x=\log\bigg(\frac{(2a+1)^{2a+1}(2b+1)^{2b+1}}{(a+b+1)^{2(a+b+1)}}\bigg)$$
For example, choosing $a=9$ and $b=6$, we have
$$\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{x^9-x^6}{\log(x)}\bigg)^2 \text{d}x=\log\bigg(\frac{(19)^{19}(13)^{13}}{(16)^{32}}\bigg)$$

I could not prove the result by any method actually.
I am interested in the proof of this result, using both real method and complex method, not only one.
Is there a known resource for proofs of such amazing results?

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Where does the formula come from? If you do not have a proof then how to you know that it is true?

@MartinR I saw it in my old notebook, written as a result, no details. I forgot its source. I believe it is true just by plugging some numbers into the calculator, yet not a proof.

try using feynman's integration i think it will work
form 2 integrals: $$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2a}}{(log(x))^2}.dx$$
and, $$J(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{log(x)}.dx$$

This is mainly due to Fubini Theorem and the fact that
$$
\frac{x^a - x^b}{\log{x}} = \int_{b}^{a} x^y \ dy.
$$
See that
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{x^a - x^b}{\log{x}}\right)^2 \ dx = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{b}^{a} x^y \ dy\right)^2 \ dx = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{b}^{a} x^y \ dy\right) \left(\int_{b}^{a} x^z \ dz\right) \ dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{b}^{a}\int_{b}^{a} x^{y} x^{z} \ dy \ dz \ dx = \int_{b}^{a}\int_{b}^{a}\int_{0}^{1} x^{y+z} \ dx \ dy \ dz = \int_{b}^{a}\int_{b}^{a} \frac{dy \ dz}{1+z+y} \\
&= \int_{b}^{a} \log{(1+z+a)} - \log{(1+z+b)} \ dz \\
&= \left((1+z+a)\log{(1+z+a)} - z\Biggr|_{b}^{a}\right) - \left((1+z+b)\log{(1+z+b)} - z\Biggr|_{b}^{a}\right) \\
&= (1+2a)\log{(1+2a)} - (a+b+1)\log{(a+b+1)} - \left((1+a+b)\log{(1+a+b)}-(1+2b)\log{(1+2b)}\right),
\end{align*}
which is exactly the result you wanted, in the end I used that
$$
\int \log{(\alpha+x)} \ dx = (\alpha+x)\log{(\alpha+x)} - x + c
$$

Let $I$ be the original integral and define
$$I(u,v)=\int_0^1\frac{x^u-x^b}{\log(x)}\frac{x^v-x^b}{\log(x)} \text{d}x.$$
Then $I(b,v)=I(u,b)=0$ and $I(a,a)=I$. Note
$$ \frac{\partial I(u,v)}{\partial u\partial v}=\int_0^1x^{u+v}\text{d}x=\frac1{u+v+1}x^{u+v+1}\bigg|_{x=0}^1=\frac1{u+v+1}.$$
So
$$ \frac{\partial I(a,v)}{\partial v}=\int_b^a\frac{\partial I(u,v)}{\partial u\partial v}du=\int_b^a\frac{1}{u+v+1}du=\log(a+v+1)-\log(b+v+1) $$
and hence
$$I(a,a)=\int_b^a(\log(a+v+1)-\log(b+v+1))dv=\log\bigg(\frac{(2a+1)^{2a+1}(2b+1)^{2b+1}}{(a+b+1)^{2(a+b+1)}}\bigg).$$

Let $x=e^t$ and expand
$$I=\int \Bigg(\frac{e^{(2 a+1)t}}{t^2}+\frac{e^{(2 b+1)t}}{t^2}-2\frac{e^{(a+ b+1)t}}{t^2}\Bigg)\,dt$$
$$J=\int \frac{e^{kt}}{t^2}\,dt=k \,\text{Ei}(k t)-\frac{e^{k t}}{t}$$ Back to $x$ and the bounds
$$I=(2 a+1) \log (2 a+1)+(2 b+1) \log (2 b+1)-2 (a+b+1) \log (a+b+1)$$ which is your formula.
